# How do we position the text boxes and other gwt widgets using css, after having positioned them using window builder

Tags: css, gwt

I am new to GWT, I am trying to apply style to the pages that I created using CSS
How do we position the text boxes and other gwt widgets using css, after having positioned them using window builder.
I tried using relative positioning but the text boxes are overlapping with the labels that i dragged and dropped using window builder.
 please suggest me how I can style it without the over lapping

Answer (score 0):

You have to alter their style attribute at runtime : you have a good starting point  in [Declarative Layout with UiBinder](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder#Hello_Stylish_World).

Object annotated with @UiField are widgets and you can manipulate like [this](http://blog.francoismaillet.com/?p=68).